# React Scroll button dosent change

Tags: css, reactjs

I have never done alot of designing when it comes to scrolls in react but decided to try today. From my understand the way to do is to use a wrapper and the need for using a library is not needed. I dont understand why nothing happens to my scroll button?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ArrowCircleRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowCircleRight';
const SendMessageUser = () => {
    const styles = {
        main: {
            height: "100%",
            position: "relative"
        },
        wrapper: {
            height: "100%",
            position: "relative",
            "::-webkit-scrollbar": {
                width: "20px"
            },
            "::-webkit-scrollbar-track": {
                backgroundColor: "transparent"
            },
            "::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
                backgroundColor: "#d6dee1",
                borderRadius: "20px",
                border: "6px solid transparent",
                backgroundClip: "content-box"
            },
            "::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover": {
                backgroundColor: "#a8bbbf"
            }
        },
        textArea: {
            height: "100%", overflowY: "auto", width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#fff", resize: "none", border: "none", outline: "none", padding: "10px 25px 10px 10px", fontSize: "15px",
        }
    };
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setMessage(event.target.value);
    };
    const sendMessage = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    return (
        <form className="send-message" onSubmit={(event) => sendMessage(event)} style={styles.main}>
            <div style={styles.wrapper}>
                <textarea spellcheck="false" data-gramm="false" data-gramm_editor="false" data-enable-grammarly="false" style={styles.textArea}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit, ipsum in hendrerit laoreet, ligula ipsum commodo nisl, eu commodo est nulla quis dolor.</textarea>
            </div>
            <ArrowCircleRightIcon color="primary" sx={{
                position: "absolute",
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                transform: "rotate(-90deg)",
            }} />
        </form >
    )
}

export default SendMessageUser
```